# How can I reconnect the pull chain to my fan?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I made the biggest mistake I just took the old switch out and wasn't paying attention to how the wires were hooked to the old pull chain, the pull chain I have has 2 black wires and in the fan there is red,blue and white. Can you help me out please? No I have no idea the name of the fan (OLD)

[image]

Comment: Some photos of the disassembled fan wiring would be useful here. Color alone isn't going to be enough to answer. Also, how many wire nuts did you disconnect? And lastly, does this one pull chain control a light and the fan at the same time?

Comment: there is 2 pull switches, 1 for the fan and one for the light. I made a mistake the red wire is not loose it is going into a small black box. I am trying to figure out how to ad a picture

Comment: So how many wire nuts did you disconnect? And just to be sure, this ONE switch did not stop the fan and light at the same time right? (some people wire these this way even tho it isnt as intended). For posting a pic, try tinypic.com and link the picture here

Comment: Damn must be getting old its the light set up that has me confused, the 2 new black wires from the switch and the old black and white one that was there, so 4 and no this is just for the light the fan was working but couldn't turn off the light.

Comment: <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=25z2c15" target="_blank"><img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/25z2c15.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

Comment: Thanks for the picture!!! The answer below is right. The color wont matter. You're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers in the questions (and the missing answers) I believe this is the answer. I'll restate the problem and if my restatement agrees with your situation then the answer is valid. If there is anything "extra" or still leaving you concerned, ask before proceeding.

Disclaimer: Without pictures it is hard to say with absolute certainty. Always hire an electrician if in doubt, or in a case like this, ask a trusted friend or family member to review the problem and the recommended solution. Hooking up wires incorrectly could be a fire hazard.

Based on your answers:

1. You had a switch you disconnected
2. Said switch had two wires going in to it, one was white, one was black
3. When you removed the switch, the white and black wires mentioned in #2 went with it (were a part of the switch)
4. Assuming #3 is correct, there had to be "wire nuts" or some other screw terminal that the white and black wire connected to, based on what you said, these were wire nuts connecting to a white, blue, or red wire that is part of the wire harnesses in the fan.
5. The Red wire you have since determined is connected where it needs to be and is NOT suspect nor was it disturbed nor disconnected during switch removal
6. The only wires that are "exposed" on the fan wire harness side is a single WHITE and a single BLUE
7. No other wire nuts were removed or other wires exposed during switch removal
8. The NEW switch comes with two wires, they are both black

If 1-8 match your situation, then (For each wire by itself) if needed, straighten the copper exposed wire ends, so they are all inline with each other (not frayed or bent up) and then twist them a 1/4 turn to 1/2 turn in your thumb and index finger so that [They look like this... courtesy of Google image search](https://ogrforum.ogaugerr.com/fileSendAction/fcType/0/fcOid/64640221070561253/filePointer/64640221070561296/fodoid/64640221070561292/imageType/LARGE/inlineImage/true/20160921_221419.jpg)

Then take a black wire from the switch, and line it up with the blue wire from the fan and using the wire nut placed over the very top of this pair, twist clockwise until the cap feels tight. It screws on and is secure. Using electrical tape for good measure can help ensure this stays connected.

Repeat the process above for the OTHER black wire on the switch, and then pair it up with the WHITE wire from the fan.

You are done.

As a quick note, the wire color in this case really doesn't matter. The fact that the switch uses two black instead of a white and a black like the old switch also doesn't matter. What matters is that we only have two wire to connect to in the fan.